# glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST) not working?

Tags: opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, opengl-es-1.1

when I enable the lighting in the opengl es, I suddenly found the depth test fails to work. It looks some object is transparent after some rotation. Handle should be invisible from this angle.

I am using glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST) in the beginning.

I am using OpenGL ES 2.0

Anything can be wrong?

When I don't use light, everything looks fine.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you sure you clear the depth buffer before rendering ?

```
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
```

EDIT :

Also check if you actually activate the depth framebuffer from your windowing API.

If you use GLUT for instance, when calling `glutInitDisplayMode` your must provide `GLUT_DEPTH` as parameter.

Comment: Yes, I have this before the rendering, but I still get the same result.

Comment: BTW, I am using VBO to draw.

Comment: It may be from an user issue like : do you actually activate the depth framebuffer from your windowing API ? If you use GLUT for instance, when calling glutInitDisplayMode your must provide GLUT_DEPTH as parameter.

Comment: @AdamLee: If you render to an FBO, make sure that your FBO has a depth attachment. The depth buffer from your default framebuffer will not be used when rendering to an FBO. You need to create a depth renderbuffer, and attach it to the FBO.

Answer (score 0):

Call this:

```
gl.glDepthMask( true );
```

I spent one day to solve this :)